# looping over an array inside hql?

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy

I have an array of ids which i want to loop over inside the update query. I have tried with couple of ways but got some errors.

```
hql = """UPDATE items
                 SET nOrder = CASE id
                """
        //l1 is the list of ids.
        for(int i = 0; i <= l1.size(); i++) {
            hql += "\n WHEN ${l1[i]} THEN ${i}"
        }
        hql += "\n END"
        hql += "\n WHERE id IN (:id)"
        Items.executeUpdate(hql,[id: l1])
```

even i have tried like this got the same error.

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= l1.size(); i++) {
            Items.executeQuery("UPDATE Items SET nOrder = CASE id WHEN ${l1[i]} THEN ${i}  END WHERE id IN (:id)",[id: l1])
}
```

error message.

**expecting "then", found ',' near line 1, column 61 [UPDATE org.items SET nOrder = CASE id WHEN 2,1 THEN 0 END WHERE id IN (:id)]**

can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong in it ?

Comment: `i<=l1.size()` looks very odd

Comment: is there better way to count the records ?

Comment: the `<=` is the odd part here. usually `size()` returns the size, so a for loop from 0 on would need `i<x.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are building SQL from (user provided?) strings, which is a horrible idea.  The error there boils down to: `WHEN 2,1 THEN 0`, which is invalid SQL (note the `,` there).  You are most probably have some float stored as string in `${l1[i]}` or running with a locale, where digits are separated with `,`, etc.  You should use the param replacement (like you already do for `:id`) also in all the other places (no `${l1[i]}` and `$i`). E.g.:

```
l1.eachWithIndex{ id, order ->
    Items.executeQuery("UPDATE Items SET nOrder=:order WHERE id=:id",[id:id, order:order])
}
```

Comment: heree i am trying to loop over an array of ids which are stored in l1. And also I am updating list of multiple records and I am passing list of ids in where clause. will you please tell me why id, order ?

Comment: This code is simply an example.  If you want the `case ... then` behaviour, you will most likely have to build a map.  The key here is not using ${} text replacements within SQL statements.